# Accessing index in a TypeScript indexible interface

Tags: dictionary, typescript

I’ve created a “Dictionary” in typescript using index types and are trying to use it as an array in a for in statement. I am able to get the value without problem, but can't figure out how I can access the index as well (see the ?? in the for loop).

```
export interface Settings {
    dictionary : IDictionary[];
}

export interface IDictionary{
    [index: number]: string;
}

// To be used like this
for (var setting in Settings.dictionary)
{
  console.log(“Setting is: “ + setting + “ for id: “ + ??);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full working example of your code... essentially all your interfaces are spot on and you just need to adjust that bit in your loop as you indicated with the `???`.

The key is `setting`

To get the value, use `settings.dictionary[setting]`

Here is the full code:

```
export interface Settings {
    dictionary : IDictionary[];
}

export interface IDictionary{
    [index: number]: string;
}

function logSettings(settings: Settings) {
    for (var setting in settings.dictionary) {
        console.log('Setting is: ' + settings.dictionary[setting] + 
            ' for id: ' + setting);
    }
}

var settings: Settings = {
    dictionary: []
};

settings.dictionary[0] = 'A';
settings.dictionary[1] = 'B';

logSettings(settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, setting is the ID. The value you need to index which you can do using [id]

Learn more about for/in : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in